# How to uninstall PostGIS legacy (pre extensions)

Tags: postgresql, postgis

This may seem like a dump question. But, I have this legacy database which was running PostGIS (but isn't anymore) and still has lots of PostGIS specific code in the dump. Stuff like this:

```
CREATE TYPE box2d (
    INTERNALLENGTH = 65,
    INPUT = box2d_in,
    OUTPUT = box2d_out,
    ALIGNMENT = int4,
    STORAGE = plain
);
```

and

```
CREATE FUNCTION _st_concavehull(param_inputgeom geometry) RETURNS geometry
    LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT
    AS $$
        DECLARE
        vexhull GEOMETRY;
        var_resultgeom geometry;
        var_inputgeom geometry;
        vexring GEOMETRY;
        cavering GEOMETRY;
        cavept geometry[];
        seglength double precision;
        var_tempgeom geometry;
        scale_factor integer := 1;
        i integer;

        BEGIN

                -- First compute the ConvexHull of the geometry
                vexhull := ST_ConvexHull(param_inputgeom);
                var_inputgeom := param_inputgeom;
                ...
```

(You get the idea).

I'm fine with losing any GIS related data, of which I shouldn't have any. I'm also fine in dumping and reloading, though it would obviously be better to not do that.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a tool for uninstall olt postgis stuff, but if you remove the postgis types using `DROP TYPE ... CASCADE;`, you will remove also the majority of the postgis functions. Postgis types are: `geometry`,  `geometry_dump`, `box2d`, `box3d`, `geography` and maybe some more.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I presume, that will also remove the functions, right?

Comment: Yes it does, I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, since there doesn't seem to be an official uninstall script (that I'm aware of), this is the script I was running in the end, to remove all data types and functions created by postgis:

```
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS box2d CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS box2df CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS box3d CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS geography CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS geometry CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS geometry_dump CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS gidx CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS pgis_abs CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS spheroid CASCADE;
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS valid_detail CASCADE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spatial_ref_sys CASCADE;

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _postgis_join_selectivity(regclass, text, regclass, text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS _postgis_stats(tbl regclass, att_name text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS checkauth(text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS checkauthtrigger() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dropgeometrytable(table_name character varying) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dropgeometrytable(schema_name character varying, table_name character varying) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_analyze(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_gist_compress(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_gist_decompress(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_gist_penalty(internal, internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_gist_picksplit(internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_gist_union(bytea, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_typmod_in(cstring[]) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_typmod_out(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_analyze(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_compress_2d(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_compress_nd(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_decompress_2d(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_decompress_nd(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_penalty_2d(internal, internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_penalty_nd(internal, internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_picksplit_2d(internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_picksplit_nd(internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_union_2d(bytea, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_union_nd(bytea, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_typmod_in(cstring[]) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_typmod_out(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gettransactionid() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gserialized_gist_joinsel_2d(internal, oid, internal, smallint) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gserialized_gist_joinsel_nd(internal, oid, internal, smallint) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gserialized_gist_sel_2d(internal, oid, internal, integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS gserialized_gist_sel_nd(internal, oid, internal, integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lockrow(text, text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lockrow(text, text, text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lockrow(text, text, text, timestamp without time zone) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_cache_bbox() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_constraint_dims(geomschema text, geomtable text, geomcolumn text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_constraint_srid(geomschema text, geomtable text, geomcolumn text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_constraint_type(geomschema text, geomtable text, geomcolumn text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_geos_version() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_lib_build_date() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_lib_version() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_libjson_version() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_libxml_version() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_proj_version() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_scripts_build_date() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_scripts_installed() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_scripts_released() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_svn_version() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_type_name(geomname character varying, coord_dimension integer, use_new_name boolean) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_typmod_dims(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_typmod_srid(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_typmod_type(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_version() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_area(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_asewkt(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_asgeojson(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_asgml(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_askml(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_assvg(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_astext(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_coveredby(text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_covers(text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_distance(text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_dwithin(text, text, double precision) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_intersects(text, text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_length(text) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_relatematch(text, text) CASCADE;
```

Comment: Nice work, but PLPGSQL is not specific to postgis but the native Postgres procedural language. This is line is a error and must be removed: `DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS plpgsql CASCADE;`

Comment: Haha, nice catch, thank you! I haven't already deployed it, so that's a close one.

Answer (score 0):

Found some more:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS box3d_extent_in(cstring) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS box3d_extent_out(box3d_extent) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS chip_in(cstring) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS chip_out(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS compression(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS datatype(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS factor(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_gist_join_selectivity(internal, oid, internal, smallint) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_gist_selectivity(internal, oid, internal, integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_typmod_dims(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_typmod_srid(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geography_typmod_type(integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_joinsel(internal, oid, internal, smallint) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS geometry_gist_sel(internal, oid, internal, integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS height(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lwgeom_gist_compress(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lwgeom_gist_decompress(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lwgeom_gist_penalty(internal, internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lwgeom_gist_picksplit(internal, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS lwgeom_gist_union(bytea, internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_gist_joinsel(internal, oid, internal, smallint) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_gist_sel(internal, oid, internal, integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS postgis_uses_stats() CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS setfactor(chip, real) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS setsrid(chip, integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS srid(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_chip_in(cstring) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_chip_out(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_compression(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_datatype(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_factor(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_geometry_analyze(internal) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_height(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_postgis_gist_joinsel(internal, oid, internal, smallint) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_postgis_gist_sel(internal, oid, internal, integer) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_setfactor(chip, real) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_srid(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS st_width(chip) CASCADE;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS width(chip) CASCADE;

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS geography_columns CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS geometry_columns CASCADE;
```

In addition, the following is commented out:

```
sed -i 's/^CREATE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql;/-- CREATE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql;/g' db.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this.
Extensions are providing an uninstall script : uninstall_legacy.sql
It exists since at least 2.0.0.
I've been able to run this script on a 2.4.4 extension and upgrade it to 3.2.3 immediately afterwards.